# What is the correct way to punctuate this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Is it "Anyone who wants to can." OR "Anyone who wants to, can."?

Comment: One might ask.. to can what? Welcome to the site, Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and take a look through the help centre to familiarise yourself with our ways: https://english.stackexchange.com/help  You might consider joining our sister site for English language learners here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Doe it not call for parenthetical commas? - "Anyone, who wants to, can."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two arguments in favour of the alternative with the comma, but please note that the use of commas is disputed territory and different style guides may give different advice.

The first argument is to do with helping the reader who might be misled by seeing "to can" and then try to interpret those words as an infinitive.

The second argument is to do with how the sentence would be spoken. There would be a pause after 'to' and before 'can'. The comma indicates such a pause.